# Generating text files

Tags: php, xml, xspf

My apologies but this is a How to Question. I have limited knowledge of PHP and need figure out if PHP can do this

I have a list of video files that I need tagged with xspf files. And there are thousands of them all in the same directory!

How to make a PHP script read the video file names and create a text file with the video file name inside the text file with other pre-created text and then save the text file the same name as the video file(not the extension)

I searched and could only find a mp3 xspf generator but it creates one playlist of all the mp3 files it found in one directory.. I need to create a xspf file for each video(MP4) file  in a directory - http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-xspf-gen/

Or if anyone knows of an windows App that can do the same...

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with xspf files, but creating a file for each video file is pretty easy.

```
$videoDir = 'C:/path/to/video';
$textDir = 'C:/path/to/textfiles';
foreach(scandir($videoDir) as $filename){
    file_put_contents($textDir.'/'.$filename.'.txt', 'Text to put in file');
}
```

Some additional Code will be needed, but I hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: Your code will create a file called ".(dot).txt" and ".(dot-dot).txt" `.txt` and `..txt`

Comment: True, but it was supposed to be a pointer in the right direction and not finished code :) If you want to get rid of the (dot) files, you can use the is_file() check.

Comment: Or... "he" can use the `if_file()` check ;-) just thought I'd point that out. Cheers